# This object does not have an attribute named "az"

Tags: terraform

I'm new to terraform and could use some help please. I had some basic config to build a VPC and two subnets with instances. This ran successfully when I did a 'terraform apply'. Now running a terraform destroy and getting the error in the title. Even running terraform plan to see if anything has changed just throws the same error. The full error says

```
      each.value is object with no attributes 
This object does not have an attribute named "az".
```

I'm guessing there's something relating to the 'for_each' function i've not done right. But then i'm not sure how it applied successfully. I've checked and the resources created from the apply are still there.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "iperf_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ireland_vpc.id
  for_each = var.private_subnets
  cidr_block = each.value.subnet
  availability_zone = each.value.az
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "private_subnets" {
  type = map(object({}))
}
```

exercise.tfvars

```
private_subnets = {
    host_a = {
        az = "eu-west-1a"
        subnet = "172.30.1.0/25"
        }      
    host_b = {
        az = "eu-west-1b"
        subnet = "172.30.1.128/25"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the type of the variable `private_subnets` to be `map(object({}))`. Since the `object` does not have any attributes explicitly specified, Terraform will throw an error.

You should change this to `map(map(string))` or to `map(object({az = string, subnet = string}))` if you want be more specific.

Comment: hi....thank you very much. That worked. I'll go back and review to make sure I understand that objects better. I still don't understand how it worked when applying terraform initially but threw the error when trying to destroy.